# Hibernate Projection group by issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two table as follows :

Configuration(id, config, created_at, meta_id, status)

I seek the latest config and its type for each meta_id. I wrote following hibernate query but only got meta_id and created_at due to the usage of projection with group_by. Is there any way I can get config too with adding it to group_by clause?

```
Criteria query = currentSession().createCriteria(Configuration.class).setProjection(
                     Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("meta_id"))
                    .add( Projections.max("created_at") ));
    List configList = query.list();
```

Comment: where is second table?

Comment: The second table looks this mata-info( id, environment, version, type)